# How to re-create service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I have loadbalancer service in my EKS cluster. Due to some issue load balancer is not working. is there any way i can re-create it like how we delete pod it automatically creates?

Comment: Can you check out the YAML file from source control, and repeat `kubectl apply -f service.yaml`?  Note that normally the act of creating a Service doesn't necessarily trigger anything, so if you delete a Service and recreate an identical one, it will probably behave the same way.

Comment: How is it "not working"? Normally if you `kubectl describe svc {name-of-service}` the events section at the bottom will give you some indication what is wrong.